# How to access tables with same name different case in DB2

Tags: command-line, db2

I create the following two tables that only differs the case:

tables.sql:

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (C1 INTEGER);
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (1);
CREATE TABLE "t1" (C1 INTEGER);
INSERT INTO "t1" VALUES (2);
CREATE TABLE T2 (C1 INTEGER, "c1" integer);
INSERT INTO T2 VALUES (3, 4);
```

Command

```
db2 -tvf tables.sql
```

When I want to query the tables, directly from the CLP, I cannot differentiate the two types of case. How can I do a query to table T1 and another to table t1. The same for both columns C1 and c1?

Comment: Needless to say, this is a good example of why you should never use tables named this way.  In fact, any time you have to delimit table names (like if they include spaces, or are reserved words), you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: Yes, that is true, and this could happens when using DDL for multi databases, because some of them includes quotes and DB2 understand them differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to query those tables from CLP in Windows, you have to do:

For table T1 (The simplest one):

```
db2 select * from T1
```

or (This is the way in Linux because of the *)

```
db2 "select * from T1"
```

For table t1

```
db2 "select * from ""t1"""
```

For the columns is similar

```
db2 select C1 from T2
```

For the other

```
db2 "select ""c1"" from T2"
```

Make sure that the whole command is involve in quotes. If you issue this command:

```
db2 select ""c1"" from T2
```

It will return C1 instead. The same for this command:

```
db2 select * from ""t1""
```

with T1 being returned.

Comment: I think, this should apply when issuing SQL from embeded SQL inside a SQC file or SQLJ file.

Comment: It also works: db2 select * from """t1""" (three times quotes)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using CLP on a linux shell, the shell will interpret the quotes and strip them.  On Linux / Unix escape the quotes with backslashes

```
db2 "INSERT INTO \"t1\" VALUES (...)"
```